# DB Error -1 when upgrading a WordPress based installation from 4.7.20 to 4.7.23

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I got the following message when trying to upgrade from 4.7.20 to 4.7.23. Installation is WP-based with 2 languages: Hungarian (primary) and English-US.

PHP 5.6.30 is used.

```
[Error: Upgrade DB to 4.7.21]
Hiba mező   Hiba érték
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_batch_en_US AS SELECT id, name, created_id, created_date, modified_id, modified_date, saved_search_id, status_id, type_id, mode_id, total, item_count, payment_instrument_id, exported_date, data, title_en_US title, description_en_US description FROM civicrm_batch [nativecode=1347 ** 'wordpress.civicrm_batch_en_US' is not VIEW]
DebugInfo   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_batch_en_US AS SELECT id, name, created_id, created_date, modified_id, modified_date, saved_search_id, status_id, type_id, mode_id, total, item_count, payment_instrument_id, exported_date, data, title_en_US title, description_en_US description FROM civicrm_batch [nativecode=1347 ** 'wordpress.civicrm_batch_en_US' is not VIEW]
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
Exception trace
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  unknown:unknown
1   call_user_func(Array, Object(DB_Error)) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:921
2   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: unknow…', -1, 16, Array, 'CREATE OR REPLAC…')    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php:985
3   DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, Array, 'CREATE OR REPLAC…')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:575
4   PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -1, null, null, 'CREATE OR REPLAC…', 'DB_Error', true)   unknown:unknown
5   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:224
6   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1905
7   PEAR->raiseError(null, -1, null, null, 'CREATE OR REPLAC…', 'DB_Error', true)   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1905
8   DB_common->raiseError(-1, null, null, null, '1347 ** 'wordpre…')    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:933
9   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:403
10  DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('CREATE OR REPLAC…') /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1216
11  DB_common->query('CREATE OR REPLAC…')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2446
12  DB_DataObject->_query('CREATE OR REPLAC…')  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1635
13  DB_DataObject->query('CREATE OR REPLAC…')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:362
14  CRM_Core_DAO->query('CREATE OR REPLAC…', false) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/I18n/Schema.php:348
15  CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(Array, '4.7.21')    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:396
16  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processLocales('/var/www/html/wp…', '4.7.21') /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:427
17  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processSQL('4.7.21')  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:717
18  CRM_Upgrade_Form::doIncrementalUpgradeStep(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), '4.7.21', '4.7.20', '4.7.23', '/tmp/civicrm-pos…')    unknown:unknown
19  call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:88
20  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:214
21  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:52
22  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:106
23  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:54
24  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  unknown:unknown
25  call_user_func(Array)   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:276
26  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:84
27  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:52
28  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1227
29  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   unknown:unknown
30  call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:298
31  WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)   /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:323
32  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
33  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php:222
34  {main}
```